# Movesense Showcase IOS App (1.0.3) cannot update firmware OTA

Tags: movesense

[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLgtq.png) Error: operationError(Operation failed)
This is IOS 13.3. mobile device. Sensor is core: 1.1.0.
The sensor works fine with the app, and the DFU update does put the device in dfu mode (led on), but does not upload anything.
I'm trying to upload the most recent jumpmeter_app.zip (no version#).

Does the firmware zip filename need to start with Movesense_xxx.zip?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is usually appreciated if askers waste a minute and provide error messages as text instead of a screenshot. I also wonder what might be considered 'recent' and if this will change over time. If you think so, you could just replace 'recent' with some explicit version number.

Answer (score 0):

Movesense firmware updated the bootloader and BLE stack on version 1.2. That means that when updating from version <1.2 to >=1.2 you'll need to use the Movesense_xxxx**_w_bootloader**.zip DFU package. Between the big version jumps the smaller DFU package (without *_w_bootloader* in name) works fine and is much faster to update.

If there is a problem in the actual update with the Showcase app (iOS or Android) even if the sensor goes to DFU mode just fine, it is a good idea to try to run the update with the "nRF Connect" app (by Nordic Semiconductor) from app store.

Just for your information, the same situation will be between <= 1.9.4 and (coming) v. >=2.0.

*Full disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*